# Protecting External Connector Ground Pin from ESD

Tags: grounding, esd, ground-plane

I have some TRS (stereo phone) connectors on my protable USB device (no earth ground), and I'm wondering what to do about ESD events that enter the device via the sleeve (ground) of the connector.

Currently I have the TRS ground connected directly to the ground plane of the PCB, and I've noticed that an ESD event can cause my device to reset and very occasionally completely hang.

As a test, I added a 0.1uF capacitor between the TRS connector ground pin and VCC such the the TSR is still connected directly to ground, but also has a capacitor to VCC. This has seemed to stopped the device from resetting.  I've been googling my brains out, but I can't seem to get much indication as to whether this is a good practice, or indeed if there is something else I should be doing instead.

I'm particularly worried that the capacitor will have an adverse affect on analog measurements of the piezos plugged into the TRS connectors.  The signal from the piezo goes off to an opamp buffer and I just want to make sure that the capacitor used in the situation will not affect my signal integrity.

I might have also seen that a ferrite bead in series with the TRS connector ground pin before it goes to the ground plane might also be effective.

I would love to hear any advise and wisdom you can share.  Thank-you for taking the time to read this post.